# How to recreate "highlight" selection with Javascript mouse events and CSS?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, highlight, textselection

I wish to recreate the ability to highlight text.

**Highlight the above sentence.** You see that blue color that engulfs the selected text? The one letting you know that that is the text you have selected, down to the character; I want to recreate that as well as change it's color.

How could you recreate highlight - maybe not exactly - with the mouse events provided in the language? Some combination of mousedown, mousemove, mouseup and etcetera?

How is selection defined? Is it positional, where the mousedown creates a point of origin, the mouseup creates an end, and the difference is the selection? If so, then how do you access that grid information?

I don't really know where to start or the lingo that could give me any sort of useful search result. *What I aim to do is somehow tie the highlighting functionality to a keyboard button*, which is why I wish to recreate it's functionality.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range) is always a good search result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the color of the selection with this css code:

```
::selection {
    background: #ffb7b7; /* Safari */
}

::-moz-selection {
    background: #ffb7b7; /* Firefox */
}
```

(Example is [here](http://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/))

For the other things, look at Teemus comment ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range))

Comment: Thanks! Thinks it would be possible to dynamically change the CSS based on the button pressed in the keyboard while selecting? Green for holding G, red for holding R, so on?